# .getAbsolutePath() function works differently in eclipse and cmd

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, cmd, absolute-path

I have a program that scans a file.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class testProgram {

private static Scanner scan;
private static File file;
private static String filePath;
private static String content;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    
    filePath = "files\\text.txt";
    
    file = new File(filePath);
    file.getAbsoluteFile();
    
    try {
        
        scan = new Scanner(file);
        
        while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
            
            content = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println(content);
            
        }
        
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        
    } 
    
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        
        System.out.println("file not found");
        Thread.sleep(10000);

    }

}

}
```

I tried to run this in eclipse and it works fine. The absolute path shows like this:

"D:\Programming\Java\Test Program\files\text.txt"

When I compiled it into batch file and run the program in cmd, the program doesn't work because the absolute path is now different:

"D:\Programming\Java\Test Program\src\files\text.txt"

This is what my batch file looks like:

echo off

cls

java testProgram

Although the java file (the one that works in Eclipse) and the batch file (that doesn't work) were in the same folder but the batch file acts differently in terms of file paths. I want them to work in eclipse or in cmd. Why does this happen and is it possible to resolve this? Sorry for the trouble, Beginner here :)

Comment: `file.getAbsoluteFile();` - this statement does nothing - you never assign returned value to anything. A proper IDE should highlight that.

Comment: What do you expect to get on using in your Java code a file name with a path relative to current directory of the running process? `getAbsoluteFile()` returns the full qualified file name (drive + path + name + extension) independent on existence of a file with that full file name. That is like using in a command prompt window `cd /D %SystemRoot% & for %I in (AnyFolder\AnyFile.txt) do @echo %~fI`. There is output `C:\Windows\AnyFolder\AnyFile.txt` although there is no such file.

Comment: The Windows kernel function used by `cmd.exe` and by `java.exe` tries to find the file, but returns nevertheless the file name with absolute path on not finding the file in file system. The function is not for testing the existing of a file. There is a different function for that purpose. You expect that current directory of a running process/executable is always identical to directory containing the executable. That is a completely wrong expectation. An executable can be started from any directory which is the current directory for the running executable if the executable does not change it.

Comment: Look on the Stack Overflow search results on [\[java\] get application directory](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+get+application+directory). You have to determine the Java application directory in code of your Java application and concatenate this path by code written by you with file/folder names with a path relative to application directory or your Java application sets the current directory itself to the directory of the application which can have a UNC path. I prefer in my code always the variant with concatenation of application directory with file/folder name for any ...

Comment: ... file or folder with a path relative to application directory as on a file/folder access error the error message is with correct full qualified file/folder name which helps a user to find out the reason why a file/folder is missing or cannot be created/modified/deleted by my applications. An error message like `File "files\text.txt" not found.` is less useful in comparison to an error message like `File "C:\Program Files\Company Name\Application Name\files\test.txt" not found.` for a user of the application.

Comment: Thanks, i had just resolved the problem :) i realized that the function just gets the file's absolute path directory and it doesn't return any value. I resolved it by manually making a concatenating script that fixes the directory so that it can run on batch file or in eclipse.